# Parallel computing in N-Dimensional Arrays for Java

Tags: java, nd4j

Does the library ND4J (N-Dimensional Arrays for Java) support parallel computing as like in numpy for Python?

Comment: So what does this have to do with **[tag:Python]** and **[tag:Numpy]**?

Comment: to multiply some n-dimensional arrays for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "parallel computing", largely we're implemented in c/c++ but also support cuda as well as mkl, and power chips as well.

Due to how broad your question is, I can only assume you aren't really looking for a "deep" answer to this question but I can tell you that we have the buzzwords you'd expect like openmp, blas/lapack, sparse,..

So editing my answer a bit: Numpy operations that are "vectorized" are just for loops in c. Python inherently has slow loops and is largely a slow language.

Another edit: It would be physically impossible for us to support gpus if there wasn't a ton of  c code buried in there. We also couldn't do blas without JNI. Nd4j is definitely NOT a pure java library.

We run all the real logic in: https://github.com/deeplearning4j/libnd4j

So yes: in that effect we have "c++ based for loops" in there yes. The for loops are multi threaded or "parallelized" using cuda and openmp/mkl.

Comment: And this is not an *answer*. The question in itself is rather well-defined

Comment: for example if I use python and do some operation with arrays by using loops, it takes a lot of time. But, if I use numpy for these operation it executes very fast. So, the question is: can ND4J provide such possibilities?

Comment: I disagree that wasn't an "answer" frankly. Numpy operations are parallelized in that exact way. Those things happen via SIMD and openmp.
I still stand by my earlier response that "parlalelized" is an over loaded term that can mean multi threading, or what he *should* have used: "vectorized"

Comment: so, is ND4J parallelized too?

Comment: Please check my edit? I'm not sure what more of an answer you want.

Comment: ok, thanks. I just had to get "yes" or "no".